# Need iterator advice to traverse tree

Tags: php, iterator, spl

Hi I need some iterator advice.

I have a Category object which can contain a collection of items and also can have children categories.

From doctrine ORM I do get a collection of category objects. Now I want to traverse this collection and flatten the category tree structure. So the children categories are at the same level as it's parent. I would also like to filter the children.

Maybe somebody can point me in the right direction, currently a bit lost in the Iterator cloud.

```
<?php

class Category
{
    private $name;

    private $children;

    private $type;

    private $parent;

    private $items;

    //parent category
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function setItems($items)
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }


    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    //colelction of categories
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like a "gimmeh teh codez" question

Comment: No, I ask for advice, so give me advice, mainly which iterator to pick...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to implement the [RecursiveIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php) interface. Then, you can iterate over it using the concrete [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).

To help you understand...

A `RecursiveIterator` isn't very, um, "recursive" by itself. It is just something that offers up certain methods that can be used to get the children(the subproblem in recursion can be thought of as "children"). Notice that `RecursiveIterator.getChildren`() must return its children in the form of another `RecursiveIterator`.

You could manually iterate a plain `RecursiveIterator`, but, it would be pretty painful to keep track of all the sub iterators returned by the recursive calls to `getChildren`, and maintain the proper depth etc...thats where `RecursiveIteratorIterator` comes in...

A `RecursiveIteratorIterator` is the thing that does the actual work to systematically traverse the structure, mimicking recursion. It iterates through a `RecursiveIterator` as if it were a flat list, but at each element in the list, it tests the current element for the presence of children. If it `hasChildren`, it calls `getChildren` and stores the reference to this new child iterator in a Stack. It manages the Stack in a fashion that provides the recursive behavior you expect(much the same way you manually transform a recursive function into an iterative version).

To be clear, you don't code your own `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, just instantiate php's concrete implementation. This class exists purely to hide the complications and manage all the many `RecursiveIterator` objects that get instantiated in the traversal process from you, and presenting the result of the traversal to you as what seems like a flat list. `RecursiveIteratorIterator` is a very complicated class internally.

As for filtering-

There's a few ways. For ease of use, I recommend to use [CallbackFilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.callbackfilteriterator.php) if you have php 5.4. Otherwise, you must extend [FilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php).

However, both of those filter the elements out after the, um, view of the recursive structure has been flattened into a list like structure. So, your filter cannot for example say "skip this entire subtree", it can only say "skip this single element". If you need to say "skip this entire subtree" you need to use [RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator.php) or extend [RecursiveFilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivefilteriterator.php) if you dont have php 5.4

you probably want to start with

```
class RecursiveCategoryIterator implements RecursiveIterator {...
```

And that should contains a list of Category objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start at the root node and [recursively traverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) each `$this->getChildren()` (of the nodes and the subnodes (and their subnodes (and their subnodes (and their subnodes)))) (recursion) until it is `null`.  This will result in something like this:

```
(Start)
Root node
-> 1st Child node
--> Grandchild node
-> 2nd Child node
-> 3rd Child node
-> 4th Child node
--> Grandhild node
(No more children so exit)
```

Comment: Any suggestions which (PHP) iterator to choose for this?

Comment: Create your own using `implements Iterator` http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php