# PHP RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, spl

So I want to show whole directory and sub directories.

According PHP Doc,

**The RecursiveDirectoryIterator provides an interface for iterating recursively over filesystem directories**

Here is my code:

```
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("c:\php_win");

foreach ($it as $dir) {
    var_dump($dir->getFilename());
}
```

Above code only shown one level directory, all sub directories not been shown.

I know I have to use RecursiveIteratorIterator to get all sub directories, but i just do not know why I need to use a RecursiveIteratorIterator iterator.

what is "**iterating recursively over filesystem directories**" mean? any web links which explains why we need a IteratorIterator?

Comment: my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955523/need-iterator-advice-to-traverse-tre/10956275#10956275 sheds a little light on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` is a class implementing the `RecursiveIterator` interface.

The `RecursiveIteratorIterator` is a class implementing the `Iterator` interface.

With a `foreach` traversal over it, it will take an object implementing `RecursiveIterator` and do a recursive traversal (tree traversal) on it, here in PHP not only rewinding, fetching current, advancing next and checking validity *but also* checking if children exists and then internally iterating over these children, too.

[image: RecursiveIteratorIterator and RecursiveDirectoryIterator diagram]

So the `RecursiveIteratorItertor` is providing object traversal in linear order *while* performing a tree traversal over a concrete `RecursiveIterator` implementaion.

So the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` is only the container. You can iterate over it straight away (e.g. with foreach), but that linear order object iteration would not do the tree traversal.

That is why the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` is there, it offers that tree traversal.

Which is exactly your case: Direct iteration over `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` only does linear object traversal. Only the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` knows how to do tree traversal on objects implementing the `RecursiveIterator` interface. As it implements the `Iterator` interface itself, it is then possible to do linear object traversal over the tree traversal.

See as well [my answer to *How does RecursiveIteratorIterator works in php*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12236744/367456), it covers the directory iterators exemplary to show the different modes of tree traversal that are possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've turned into a gist a class (`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`) that can read a directory with all its children and output a JSON or just an array.

https://gist.github.com/jonataswalker/3c0c6b26eabb2e36bc90

And a tree viewer of the output

http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/067c13